# VSTO Deployment and application do not have matching security zones

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-addins

I've created an `Excel Add-In` which works perfectly when I run it directly from `Visual Studio`, but now I need to use this `Add-In` on another computer. To do this I copied the `[AddIn].vsto` file from my project: `bin/Release/[AddIn].vsto`

The problem is that when I try to run that file on a different computer I'm getting the following error:

> Deployment and application do not have matching security zones
>   ************** Exception Text **************
>   System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Deployment and application do not have matching security zones.
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.GetManifests(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()

I've tried to Clear the oneClick cache, but still not working. Also tried the `CCleaner` Tool ...

Should this work even if the Add-In was not Deployed? Or I need to deploy it first?

Comment: I am also facing same issue, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

Files which come from other computers than your own are attached a so called zone identifier. Files from e. g. the internet are equipped with zone "3" and Windows as the OneClick installer might put some restrictions on them. "Unblocking" in the properties dialog also modifies this zone identifier, but is not creating a good user experience. I will outline two ways to work around the issue:

1. Unblock all setup files automatically
2. Build a self-extracting installer

---

### Unblocking all setup files automatically

Assuming that you use the standard folder name "pub" for the OneClick deployment package, simply add a batch file (e. g. Setup.bat) next to the "pub" directory. The batch file should contain content similar to those shown below; make sure to replace "XXX" by the corresponding folder name in your setup.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%a in (pub\*.*) do (echo.>%%a:Zone.Identifier)
FOR %%a in ("pub\Application Files\XXX\*.*") do (echo.>%%a:Zone.Identifier)
.\pub\Setup.exe
```

This solution is perfectly ok as long as you stay in-house. You can store both items in one folder (probably zip it) and the user is going to execute Setup.bat

### Build a self-extracting installer

If licensing is no problem, simply use WinZIP or WinRAR to produce a self-extracting archive which after extraction runs your setup. Otherwise you might go with 7zip similar to [this explanation](http://richardbalsley.com/how-to-create-a-silent-self-extracting-installer-for-use-with-windows-configuration-designer). However, there is a ruse with preventing the installer from removing the temporary files before out setup has finished.

**Instructions:**

Create an empty folder. I will refer to it as the **working directory**.

In the working directory, create a 7zip archive (**Installer.7z**) using 7zip. This archive should contain two top-level items:

- *pub* the OneClick setup directory after publishing
- *Installer.bat*

The *Installer.bat* should contain the following lines:

```
@ECHO OFF
robocopy pub\ ..\Installer_pub\ /mir
..\Installer_pub\Setup.exe
```

In the working directory, add **config.txt** with following content:

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
 Title="Your Application Name"
 BeginPrompt="Do you want to install?"
 ExecuteFile="setup.bat"
 ExecuteParameters=""
 ;!@InstallEnd@!
```

In the working directory, add **7zSD.sfx** which you find [in here](http://www.7-zip.org/a/lzma1604.7z).

In your working directory, you should now find Installer.7z, config.txt and 7zSD.sfx. And this is where the magic happens....

Navigate to the working directory in command line (cmd.exe) and run the following command:

```
copy /b 7zSD.sfx + config.txt + Installer.7z Installer.exe
```

Now you should see Installer.exe in your working directory. That's it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and what I had to do was not only unlock (rmb -> properties -> unlock at the bottom) the .vsto files, but also all the other contents of your youraddinname_version subfolder, like dlls and manifest. It'd be great if there was some other way of overcoming this issue, as requesting users to do this on their machines as they want to install my add-in is a pain.